# sql for first five male or female students who've got most and least marks?

Tags: mysql

my table looks like this:

```
rajesh   50
ravi     87
kamala   26
amrutha  35
```

and so on.

I need to write a query for five male or female students who've got most and least marks.

Comment: Did you need the 5 highest and lowest marks, or something else?

Comment: Does your table have column where it describes the Male or Female students ?

Comment: @Priyanshu I don't think he cares about gender, but his question is still vague even after this.

Comment: hint: oderby col DESC and orderby col ASC should do

Comment: there is no column which describes about the gender.i nees the first five students list who've got most and least marks

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to accomplish this would be to `UNION` together two queries, one which finds the students with the highest 5 marks, and the other which finds the students with the lowest five marks.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT name, mark FROM grades ORDER BY mark DESC LIMIT 5) AS t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT name, mark FROM grades ORDER BY mark LIMIT 5) AS t2
```

Comment: ASC is missing as i guess :)

Comment: @piyushjaiswal `ASC` is the default sort order.  If it is omitted it defaults to `ASC`.

Comment: I tried this and its showing me the error --incorrect usage of order by and union @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

You must have column which describes Male & Female else you can't filter data by gender.